# Facebook like button with hashtag url

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, hash

I know there are a few disussions about this but no one is really getting to the point from what i know.

Is there any possible way to pass a hashtag url with facebook like. I have ben trying in numerous ways without any success...

Here is my code so far.

```
<fb:like href="http://myurl.com/subfolder/subsub/#the-new-destination"
    layout="button_count" 
    show_faces="false"
    width="450">
</fb:like>
```

This just doesnt do it for me - Facebook only retrieves http://myurl.com/subfolder/subsub/ 
part of the url

Oh! The problem is the urls is genereated by jquery so they are dynamic and loads in content by ajax call.

Any clues?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you change the hash tag with GET parameter ? After that, you can handle it with PHP and redirect as you like

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467296/facebook-like-buttons-and-url-strings

Answer (score 1):

Hash are not transmitted over the wire. They are only to maintain context while navigating away from one page to another