# Like button issue

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I'm having a weird problem on this page www.vivopositivo.it/media/foto/guarda-chi-sorride-over-18-e-famiglie/ with the like button. I'm using PrettyPhoto to include the pictures from Flickr and open them in a lightbox. Each picture has it's own like button which shows in the lightbox and uses a specific URL such as:

http://www.vivopositivo.it/media/foto/guarda-chi-sorride-over-18-e-famiglie/#prettyPhoto[pp_gal]/1/

where the number in  #prettyPhoto[pp_gal]/1/ is the key for the specific image.

The like buttons are included with the following code:

iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href={location_href}&layout=button_count&show_faces=true&width=500&action=like&font&colorscheme=light&height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true" /iframe

where {location_href} gets replaced with the image specific URL.

This works for most of the images, but for some of them doesn't! They seem to get the like counter of the page instead, therefore, I get about 10 images which show the same 128 like counter which is obviously wrong. This seems completely random..

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Cheers,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

This is because of # in URL which identifies the image.

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467296/facebook-like-buttons-and-url-strings) for further explanation.

Comment: Hi zysoft, thanks for your reply. I read that post but I can't understand how I can solve the issue. Also, if the # is the issue, why some of them work and some others don't? they all have the # in the URL..

Comment: I believe it's a mystery of Facebook. You can make URLs without # specifically for sharing. And when user from FB comes via such URL it gets redirected to your "normal" URL containing hash. So like ...8-e-famiglie/prettyPhoto[pp_gal]/1/ which then redirects to ...8-e-famiglie/#prettyPhoto[pp_gal]/1/